# Read Integer or String array from JSON object

Tags: android, json

For one of my web services, I am getting the following response.

```
"COLUMNS": [
        "DIST_ID",
        "NAME",
        "HOME_PHONE",
        "PAID_RANK",
        "END_RANK",
        "VOL1",
        "VOL3"
    ]
"DATA": {
        "DIST_ID": [
            3,
            1002,
            1040,
            1290,
            1041,
            1421,
            7200,
            5980,
            3962,
            1070,
            9369,
        ]
    }
```

How can I parse this?

I tried like

```
JSONArray colArray = response.getJSONArray(COLUMNS);
            for(int i=0; i<colArray.length(); i++){
                if(Constants.LOG)Log.d("","Column "+colArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());
            }
```

But it didn't worked. It's throwing exception like

```
09-30 12:51:56.076: W/System.err(3003): org.json.JSONException: Value DIST_ID at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
09-30 12:51:56.076: W/System.err(3003):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96)
09-30 12:51:56.076: W/System.err(3003):     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:484)
09-30 12:51:56.076: W/System.err(3003):     at com.vl.infotrax.modules.reports.ReportsEngine.parseReportsDetailsData(ReportsEngine.java:156)
09-30 12:51:56.076: W/System.err(3003):     at com.vl.infotrax.modules.reports.ReportsEngine.retrieveReportsDetailsData(ReportsEngine.java:126)
09-30 12:51:56.076: W/System.err(3003):     at com.vl.infotrax.modules.reports.ReportsDetailsFragment$GetReportsDetailsData.doInBackground(ReportsDetailsFragment.java:66)
09-30 12:51:56.076: W/System.err(3003):     at com.vl.infotrax.modules.reports.ReportsDetailsFragment$GetReportsDetailsData.doInBackground(ReportsDetailsFragment.java:1)
09-30 12:51:56.084: W/System.err(3003):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-30 12:51:56.084: W/System.err(3003):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-30 12:51:56.084: W/System.err(3003):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-30 12:51:56.084: W/System.err(3003):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
09-30 12:51:56.084: W/System.err(3003):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
09-30 12:51:56.084: W/System.err(3003):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Any one has idea about how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JSONArray colArray = response.getJSONArray(COLUMNS);
    for(int i=0; i<colArray.length(); i++){
        Log.d("","Column "+colArray.getString(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get directly the values as `String` and not as `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the JSON string parsed using JSONTokener , please see the sample code given below

```
String strJSON = ""; // your JSON string goes here
JSONObject jObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(strJSON).nextValue();
JSONArray jAryColumns;
if(jObject.has("Columns")){
 jAryColumns = jObject.getJSONArray("Columns");// use the array as you please
}
```

Use the technique described in above snippet and retrieve the "DATA" JSON object from jObject, from that you could get "DIST_ID".